# How to redirect from child view to parent view without reloading after button click in MVC4?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi how to stop  page reloading when the button is click from **ChildView** to **Parentview**. That is

**CustomerView**

[CustomerView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfUTN.jpg)

In my CustomerView I have field called **Area** and near to area i have created one add button. suppose i enter the customer details and select the area and the area is not listed in the  dropdown  . so i need to add the area . so i click the add button . it redirect to the area partial view  from Customer view. I had create one area partial view for that area field.

**AreaPartialView**

[AreaPartialView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyJEe.jpg)

if i click the add button near to **area** it redirect to **AreaPartialView** (LocalHost/Customer/AreaPartialView). In Area Partial view i  enter the values and click the **Create** button it  save the data in DB and also it redirect to same customer view . Now my issue is  if i  enter the CustomerName ,Street,Location, Place, Alias and then only i select the area . Now the area is not listed in the Dropdown means i need to add it so i click that add button near to area. it redirect to area Partial view and i enter the values and click the create button. When i click the create button from area Partial view it redirect to Same Customer view at the  same time page get reloaded. so my data all are lost which i enter in the CustomerName ,Street,Location, Place, Alias, so i have to enter the details again . This is my issue .  I don't want to page gets reloaded when it redirect from Partial view to CutomerView  so  i decided to use ajax. But still the issue is not cleared so please any one correct my code.

**My PartialView** **ChildView**

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DisplayName, new { @class = "control-label" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DisplayName, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DisplayName)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PrintName, new { @class = "control-label" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PrintName, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PrintName)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.Label("City")
                @Html.DropDownList("CityID", "Select")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<p>
    <input type="submit" id="btncreate" value="Create" onclick='window.location ="@Url.Action("Create", "Customer" )"' />
</p>
    </fieldset>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script>
    $("#btncreate").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "Customer/Create",
            type: "get",
            data: $("Customer").serialize(),
            success: function (result) {
                $("#ShowPartailView").html(result);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

}

Actually i don't have well knowledge in ajax . so i donno what i have put in the place of  data: **$("?").serialize(),**  So please any one check my ajax code and give me the correct solution.

My Controller Coding to save data which is entered in the partial view

```
    public PartialViewResult ShowPartailView()
    {
        ViewBag.CityID = new SelectList(db.Cities, "CityID", "DisplayName");
        return PartialView("ShowPartailView");
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ShowPartailView(Area area)
    {
        ViewBag.CityID = new SelectList(db.Cities, "CityID", "DisplayName");
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            area.AreaID = Guid.NewGuid();
            area.IsActive = true;
            area.IsDeleted = false;
            area.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
            area.EditedDate = DateTime.Now;
            area.LastActiveOn = DateTime.Now;
            area.RowID = Guid.NewGuid();
            area.CreatedSessionID = Guid.NewGuid();
            area.EditedSessionID = Guid.NewGuid();
            area.OfflineMode = false;
            area.OfflineID = Guid.NewGuid();

            db.Areas.Add(area);
            db.SaveChanges();

        };


        return RedirectToAction("Create", "Customer"); 
    }
```

MY customer View ParentView

```
<div id="Area">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Area)
            @Html.DropDownList("AreaID", "Select")
            <input type='button' id=btnArea name=btnadd value='Add' onclick='window.location ="@Url.Action("ShowPartailView", "Customer" )"' />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fill the dropdown like this method, it's not reload the page and all other filed data will remain same.

```
 $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "test/filldropdown",
         data: data,
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
         success: function (jsonResult) {
               $.each(jQuery.parseJSON(jsonResult), function () {
               myDropDownList.append($("<option></option>").val(this['FieldDescription']).html(this['FieldCode']));
         });
        },
         failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
       });
```

[Click for an Example](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/688228/Bind-Dropdownlist-in-ASP-NET-using-jQuery-AJAX)

Comment: Read the question again carefully and follow the workflow. This has nothing to do with addressing OP's question.

Comment: Smit if i change the Dropdown as per you said  it will work?